# Replace two different column values in a dataframe using same condition with minimum complexity in scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Function `withColumn` can be used to replace one column at a time. I need to replace two different columns in the same condition.

I used `withColumn` two times. But I need it to be optimized.

```
val newDf: DataFrame = df.withColumn("a", when(col("b")===1, 0))
.withColumn("c", when(col("b")===1, "Y"))
```

First

```
| a | b | c |

| 5 | 1 | N |
```

expected:

```
| a | b | c |

| 0 | 1 | Y|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code wasnt exactly as in the question but for me something like this worked using maps and list of columns.

```
val tobechanged = List("a","c")
val changeRelation = Map("a"->0,"c"->"Y")
var colList=df.columns.toSeq
var updatedDF = df
for(colName <- colList){
        updatedDF = updatedDF.withColumn(colName, when(tobechanged.contains(colName), lit(changeRelation.get(colName)))
.otherwise(col(colName)))

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
val cols = df.columns:+"b":+"c"
val newDf: DataFrame = df.select(
  "*",
  when(col("b")===1, 0),
  when(col("b")===1, "Y")
 ).toDF(cols:_*)
```

or sql query

```
df.createTempView("df")
spark.sql("
select df.*, 
case when df.b = 1 then 0 else NULL end as a,
case when df.b = 1 then 0 else NULL end as c, 
from df df
")
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass two columns inside withColumn?

Comment: unfortunately no , but you can pass two "columns" to one column as array using withColumn, and then split that array column to 2 columns

Answer (score 1):

Try matching case.
give the condition and define a case. call both the withColumn from that case.
But its still calling withColumn two times

Answer (score 0):

Function `when` in Spark returns object of type `Column`. If you don't want to repeat your conditions you can extract them to separate function:

```
def whenBIsOneThen[B](value: B): Column = when(col("b")===1, value)
```

and then use it like:

```
df
 .withColumn("a", whenBIsOneThen(0))
 .withColumn("c", whenBIsOneThen("Y"))
```